# How to force the "iTunes Connect" pages to be displayed in English?

Tags: app-store-connect

Is there a way to force iTunes Connect to display its content in English and not in my local language (other than changing the locale for the whole system)? It's extremely difficult to google for phrases without having the precise english wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal, cmd, bash whatever your system has, set the locale for the session and start itunes connect from there.

Comment: Meanwhile Apple has confirmed that there is no hidden option to change the language directly in the page (sigh). So faking the locale is the only way.